# How to convert []string to ...string

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I want to have a func to scan the folder and find all the template file. Then call template.ParseFiles to parse all the templates. I use the `var tmplPathList []string` to record all the templates, and pass `tmplPathList` to `template.ParseFiles()`.

The `func ParseFiles(filenames ...string) (*Template, error)` use `... string` as parameter. The compile error `cannot use tmplPathList (type []string) as type string in argument to "html/template".ParseFiles`

How can I convert `[]string` to `... string`?

```
var tmplPathList []string
for _, file := range tmplList {
    tmplPathList = append(tmplPathList, dir + file.Name())
}
templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(tmplPathList))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can append `...` to the variable-name when calling the function to allow the slices values to be used as varargs-parameters:

```
template.ParseFiles(tmplPathList...)
```

[Demo on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/jEc4Bj8QzS)

Comment: I know there is a way, and you show me the simple way.

Comment: @Flimzy It is what I need. No more questions.